# Multi-line math fails in Quarto

Tags: pandoc, quarto

Quarto 1.2.269, Pandoc 2.19.2, XeTeX 3.141592653-2.6-0.999994

**index.qmd**

```
---
title: "Why do I get a warning and failure to convert?"
---

This works:

$$
a = \pi r^2
$$

These do not:

$$
a_n = \begin{cases}
          3n + 1  & \text{ if } n \text{ is odd} \\
          n / 2 & \text{ otherwise}
      \end{cases}
$$

$$
1 + 2 = 3 \\
3 + 2 = 5
$$
```

**_quarto.yml**

```
project:
  type: book

book:
  title: "MRE"
  chapters:
    - index.qmd

format:
  epub:
    toc: true  # whatever
```

Then, attempt rendering...

```
$ quarto render

pandoc 
  to: epub
  output-file: MRE.epub
  toc: true
  number-sections: true
  default-image-extension: png
  
metadata
  crossref:
    chapters: true
  title: MRE
  
[WARNING] Could not convert TeX math 
      a_n = \begin{cases}
            3n + 1  & \text{ if } n \text{ is odd } \\
            n / 2 & \text{ otherwise }
        \end{cases}
  , rendering as TeX
[WARNING] Could not convert TeX math 
  1 + 2 = 3 \\
  3 + 2 = 5
  , rendering as TeX:
  1 + 2 = 3 \\
  ^
  unexpected control sequence \\
  expecting "%", "\\label", "\\tag", "\\nonumber" or whitespace
Output created: _book/MRE.epub
```

...and the resulting epub looks like this:

[image: epub output]

What am I doing wrong? How do I use cases environment or multi-line math in Quarto?

Note: This works with project type website, but not with project type book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to wrap it in LateX environments, e.g. `equation` or `align` (works both in PDF and HTML outputs)

```
\begin{equation*}
    a_n = \begin{cases}
              3n + 1  & \text{ if } n \text{ is odd} \\
              n / 2 & \text{ otherwise}
          \end{cases}
\end{equation*}

\begin{align*}
1 + 2 = 3 \\
3 + 2 = 5
\end{align*}
```

Here for instance as HTML Book output:

[image]